# Unity движение персонажа

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скачал `SimpleTouchController`, все в нем ок, создаю сцену, помещаю туда объект, вешаю на него этот контроллер и начинается приколы, если джойстик внизу он идет вперед, если вверху, идет назад, если слева то он идет вправо, если с права он идет влево, что за глюк?

Движение на оборот какое-то.
Кто-то сталкивался с этим?
Как исправить?

Comment: Повернуть на 180 по часовой (или против) не подумал?)

Comment: @AlexSherzhukov, Не получается там либо одно перестает работать другое работает, либо вообще не работает.

Comment: ну судя по описанию проблемы, дело именно в том что надо развернуть. Опиши что перестает работать

Comment: @AlexSherzhukov, неправильно рассчитал траектории, видать засиделся, за место `x` сделал `y`, и за место `y` сделал `x` =), все теперь работает.